# sorting using python for complex strings

Tags: python

I have an array that contains numbers and characters, e.g. ['A 3', 'C 1', 'B 2'], and I want to sort it using the numbers in each element.

I tried the below code but it did not work

```
def getKey(item):
   item.split(' ')
   return item[1]
x = ['A 3', 'C 1', 'B 2']

print sorted(x, key=getKey(x))
```

Comment: `print sorted(x, key=getKey(x))` -> `print sorted(x, key=getKey)` . Key expects a function

Comment: Also, `return item[1]` => `return int(item[1])` unless you want 19<2

Comment: "did not work" is not a question. What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Also `def getKey(item): return int(item.split()[1])`

Answer (score 2):

To be safe, I'd recommend you to strip everything but the digits.

```
>>> import re
>>> x = ['A 3', 'C 1', 'B 2', 'E']
>>> print sorted(x, key=lambda n: int(re.sub(r'\D', '', n) or 0))
['E', 'C 1', 'B 2', 'A 3']
```

With your method;

```
def getKey(item):
    return int(re.sub(r'\D', '', item) or 0)

>>> print sorted(x, key=getKey)
['E', 'C 1', 'B 2', 'A 3']
```

Comment: I like the test case for 'E' and stripping for digits. That makes this more robust.

Answer (score 0):

What you have, plus comments to what's not working :P

```
def getKey(item):
   item.split(' ') #without assigning to anything? This doesn't change item.
                   #Also, split() splits by whitespace naturally.
   return item[1]  #returns a string, which will not sort correctly
x = ['A 3', 'C 1', 'B 2']

print sorted(x, key=getKey(x)) #you are assign key to the result of getKey(x), which is nonsensical.
```

What it should be

```
print sorted(x, key=lambda i: int(i.split()[1]))
```

Answer (score -2):

This is one way to do it:

```
>>> x = ['A 3', 'C 1', 'B 2']
>>> y = [i[::-1] for i in sorted(x)]
>>> y.sort()
>>> y = [i[::-1] for i in y]
>>> y
['C 1', 'B 2', 'A 3']
>>>
```